# (ios) CSV file to multiple arrays?

Tags: ios, arrays, csv

ok I'm learning to use xCode(5) and I want to use a csv file (screenshot) to read data to store into 7 separate arrays. However, I'm having problems separating the 7 values. I know I'm supposed to use "componentsSeparatedByString" in my case, by ","...but Idk where to place it. Any advice would be appreciated!

csv screenshot: http://i61.tinypic.com/qz5ie8.png

*7th value is " ", used for other purposes.

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

NSError *error;
NSString *allEntries = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"fighterbase.csv" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

NSArray *rows = [allEntries componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

_names      = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_origins    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_ages       = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_heights    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_weights    = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_games      = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
_images     = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < [rows count]; i++)
{
    [_names     addObject:[rows objectAtIndex:0]];
    [_origins   addObject:[rows objectAtIndex:1]];
    [_ages      addObject:[rows objectAtIndex:2]];
    [_heights   addObject:[rows objectAtIndex:3]];
    [_weights   addObject:[rows objectAtIndex:4]];
    [_games     addObject:[rows objectAtIndex:5]];
    [_images    addObject:[rows objectAtIndex:6]];
}

NSLog(@"Name: %@ Origin: %@  Age:%@", [_names objectAtIndex:0], [_origins objectAtIndex:0], [_ages objectAtIndex:0]);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [rows count]; i++)
{
    NSArray *arrayLine = [[row objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString@","];
    [_names     addObject:[arrayLine objectAtIndex:0]];
    [_origins   addObject:[arrayLine objectAtIndex:1]];
    [_ages      addObject:[arrayLine objectAtIndex:2]];
    [_heights   addObject:[arrayLine objectAtIndex:3]];
    [_weights   addObject:[arrayLine objectAtIndex:4]];
    [_games     addObject:[arrayLine objectAtIndex:5]];
    [_images    addObject:[arrayLine objectAtIndex:6]];
}
```

But in your image, I didn't see there was a 7th value, which may be crash it if it doesn't exist. Well, you said "*7th value is " "", so you may want to manage it.

Comment: That worked perfectly! I also went ahead changed the 7th value to "N/A" as well so that no problems arise later. Thank you.